# Split list and print desired output

Tags: python, list, parsing, text, split

```
import re

foo='''"a","b","c","aaa":"sdlfjlasjdfljas"'''

list=re.split('\:,\';\"',foo)
i = 0
for word in list:
    newWord = word
    newWord.split(':')
```

I am currently trying to split the string foo apart with different paramaters like commas, colons, and parenthesis... so on.

I am currently able to split the string once which gives me the string `"aaa":"alsjflajlsdjf"` all in one index. I want to be able to split it up by the colon and in a if statement find `aaa` using `word.find` to get the next string and print it out. So it would print out the gibberish.

I have successfully used a for loop to find the `aaa` part but I'm not able to print out the gibberish. Thanks for your help in advance.

Comment: The problem with your code is that `split()` doesn't modify a string "in place" (nothing does: strings are "immutable" in python). You need to save the result in a new variable, e.g. `newWord = word.split(':')`. Then you can move forward with your code.

Comment: PS. `list` is the name of the list type in python. Don't use it as a variable name, it's legal but it will bite you sooner than you think.

Comment: why are you splitting if you just want the first word after `aaa`? `.find` is also a str operations so how exactly will splitting and using find allow you to find the gibberish?

Comment: How do you get alsjflajlsdjf from sdlfjlasjdfljas?

Answer (score 2):

You can simply split your string based on none word characters (`\W`) :

```
>>> foo='''"a","b","c","aaa":"sdlfjlasjdfljas"'''
>>> 
>>> re.split(r'\W',foo)
['', 'a', '', '', 'b', '', '', 'c', '', '', 'aaa', '', '', 'sdlfjlasjdfljas', '']
```

Or for refuse of empty strings you can use `re.findall` to find the words that contains only word characters (`\w`):

```
>>> l=re.findall(r'\w+',foo)
['a', 'b', 'c', 'aaa', 'sdlfjlasjdfljas']
```

You can use get the first word with length more than one with a generator expression within `next` function :

```
>>> next(w for w in l if len(w)>1)
'aaa'
```

Or use a list comprehension to get all of them :

```
>>> [w for w in l if len(w)>1]
['aaa', 'sdlfjlasjdfljas']
```

*Note*: if you want to split a string with some characters with regex you can use following recipes :

- use a character class : `[:,.;]`
- use logical or : `':|,|\.|;'`

But using pip ('|') with `re.split` may be contains the empty strings.in that case you can use character class.

Comment: I am having trouble understanding how exactly you are finding the aaa part and then printing out whats after. I tried doing what you did with the w for w...len(w)>1 but I just get my whole list printed out because I have more 4 entries in my data file. How would I print out whats after the aaa in terms of index or however

Answer (score 1):

Your regular expression should be like this:

```
[,;:]
```

The square brackets include all characters you want to split on.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `str.translate` replacing whatever characters you want to split on with a comma and then split on a comma:

```
tbl= str.maketrans({ord(ch):"," for ch in "();:"})
print("\n".join(foo.translate(tbl).split(",")))

"a"
"b"
"c"
"aaa"
"sdlfjlasjdfljas"
```

I don't get why you want to split all the words if all you want is the word after `aaa`, str.find is not going to do much for you if you split the string, you could split from there getting the next word after using find to get the index of `aaa`.

```
ind = foo.index("aaa")
if ind != -1:
    ....
```